# Grid system in android UI development

Tags: android, layout, grid

I am switching from web design to android design. Usually website design is based on the 'grid system' eg. 12 columns, 16 columns and etc. The grid system helps organize the layout and also works well with the responsive design, if the columns are set as the percentage of the screen width. However, when i start learning android, I didnt see anyone talking about the grid system for Android. I am wondering if android developers just dont use such grid system or there are other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

There is [GridView.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)

and [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

Both have been introduced from different API levels - check your minSdk version.
Depending on your requirement, you can apply a table layout or implement a custom layout.

Go through these [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: Thx! But all those are code-related information. I am wondering if there is a grid system like what we used in website design, eg. 980px grid: 60px for each column and 20px gap in between. Do you use such kind of grid in Android UI design at all?